# Unable to update view in MVVM architecture android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I am implementing MVVM approach in my app I have created separate repository class in which I am performing network requests data is fetching properly in fragment but when there is some network error progress bar in my activity keeps on it does not stop when there is some network error. How can I update views according to repository class as progress bar is defined in fragment and network error is given by repository class?

How to hide progress bar when there is some network error?

Below is my code:

**MyRepository.class**

```
public class MyRepository {

MutableLiveData<List<Facts>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
Application application;

public MyRepository(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Facts>> getMutableLiveData(){

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.getFacts().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                         .subscribe(new Observer<List<Facts>>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onNext(List<Facts> facts) {

                                 if(facts.size() > 0 && facts != null){

                                     mutableLiveData.setValue(facts);
                                 }
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                 TastyToast.makeText(application,e.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                         TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onComplete() {

                             }
                         });

       return mutableLiveData;
   }
}
```

**HomeFragment.class**

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

 RecyclerView recycle;
 FactsAdapter adapter;
 FactsViewModel viewModel;
 ProgressBar prg;

 public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
 }

 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

recycle = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
prg = findViewById(R.id.prg); 

LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);

viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FactsViewModel.class);

viewModel.getAllFacts().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new androidx.lifecycle.Observer<List<Facts>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(List<Facts> facts) {

           prg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           
           adapter = new FactsAdapter(facts,getActivity());
           recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }); 

return view;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Fact` around a `Resource` object having a data and status.
[Resource example code](https://github.com/Pedr0Rocha/Covid19-Info/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pedrorocha/covid19info/data/network/Resource.java)

Your return type becomes Resource, `onNext` sets the data to facts and status to OK. `onError` sets the data to null and status to NETWORK_ERROR.

On your Fragment, you observe the Resource and check the status to handle errors and OK state.
[Handling resource example](https://github.com/Pedr0Rocha/Covid19-Info/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pedrorocha/covid19info/ui/main/MainFragment.java#L82)